# Get fragmentText Depends on TextCursorPosition

Tags: c#, winforms

supposedly this is my richTextBox's Text:

```
string aaa = "bbb";
Console.WriteLine(aaa);
```

and i get cursor position / textcharIndex using:

```
richtextBox1.SelectionStart;
```

how can i get the nearest word between textcursorPosition?

e.g:
cursorPosition was between W and r on
word WriteLine

how can i get the whole word "WriteLine" ?

another1:

if textCursor position was Between Co and sole
how can i get the word "Console" ?